# Style on span also applying to its child span

Tags: html, css

I have some code, I want to apply border on my parent span in a link, but my css is applying css style on both spans?

```
<div id="DownloadButton">
    <a href="DownloadMovie.php/?FileName=Assignment 1- Regular Expression (2).docx&MovieID=2179136">    
        <span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" aria-hidden="true" style="float:left;">
            </span>
                Assignment 1- Regular Expression (2).docx
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

my css code

```
#DownloadButton a span{
    font-size: 13px;
    display:inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    width:auto;
    padding:0px 10px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 05px 5px 05px 05px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

my output image http://i58.tinypic.com/amea00.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify with a child selector:

```
#DownloadButton a > span {
```

Comment: I used an id for parent div instead, btw thanks for fast reply

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change your CSS selector to this:

```
#DownloadButton a > span
```

Comment: I used an id for parent div instead, btw thanks for fast reply

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the a in the in the block of CSS. You can target it with `:not` to omit the inner `span` since it has a `class`.

```css
#DownloadButton  span:not(.glyphicon) {
    font-size: 13px;
    display:inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    width:auto;
    padding:0px 10px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 05px 5px 05px 05px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="DownloadButton">
   
  <a href="DownloadMovie.php/?FileName=Assignment 1- Regular Expression (2).docx&MovieID=2179136">    
        <span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" aria-hidden="true" style="float:left;">
            </span>
                Assignment 1- Regular Expression (2).docx
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```